# Must declare the scalar variable when reusing parameter with IDbConnection

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameterized-query

I am trying to parameterize a sql query.  I am providing a simplified version for confidentiality.  this is in asp.net 4.7 with T-SQL from C#. Store has authority to sell for us between certain dates and products also are only allowed to be sold between another set of dates that may not be the same.  This is the version from a test page that I have created, as the normal version is spread across multiple class files.  The databases are read-only from a third party.

```
int intStoreID = 12345;
DateTime dtAsOfDate = DateTime.Now;
string strConnectionString = "Data Source=fake.site.com;Initial Catalog=my_stores; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=me;Password=mypassword";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string strQ = @" SELECT * FROM stores AS s
INNER JOIN store_sales_authorities AS ssa
on s.istore_id = ssa.istore_id
INNER JOIN store_product_sales_authorities AS spsa
on s.istore_id = spsa.istore_id
INNER JOIN products AS p
on spsa.iproduct_id = p.iproduct_id
where s.istore_id = @istoreid
and ssa.dtstart_date <= @dtAsOfDate
and (ssa.dtend_date <= @dtAsOfDate or ssa.dtend_date IS NULL)
and psa.dtstart_date <= @dtAsOfDate
and (psa.dtend_date <= @dtAsOfDate or psa.dtend_date IS NULL)";

System.Data.IDbConnection dbConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
System.Data.IDbCommand dbCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
dbCommand.CommandText = strQ;
dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 999999999;
IDbDataParameter objParameter = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
objParameter.ParameterName = "@dtAsOfDate";
objParameter.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
objParameter.Value = dtAsOfDate;
IDbDataParameter objParameter2 = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
objParameter2.ParameterName = "@istoreid";
objParameter2.DbType = DbType.Int32;
objParameter2.Value = intStoreID;
dbCommand.Parameters.Add(objParameter2);
System.Data.IDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand;
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

When I run this, I receive an exception: Must declare the scalar variable "@dtAsOfDate".
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@dtAsOfDate".
```

I couldn't locate any instances of anyone parameterizing multiple instances of the same parameter, so I don't know if that is the issue.  How do I parameterize this correctly?

Comment: You're not calling `dbCommand.Parameters.Add(objParameter1);` only `dbCommand.Parameters.Add(objParameter2);
`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.